# How to write and automate tests in Git Stash

Tags: git, selenium, automated-tests, build-automation, bitbucket-server

I have an Atlassian Stash set up with the first version of my project, which is a web app, in it. I am looking for a program that allows me to write tests that test the functionality of the web app, as well as as **automate the tests anytime the source code changes in the repository**

For example, I checkout the current version of the project from the main repository, modify it, and push it back into the repository. When that happens, since a new version was pushed, I need some program to automatically (without my initiation) run the tests and display the outcomes (pass or fail for each test).

Right now I am developing on the Eclipse IDE and am using Selenium to automate the web browser tests. But Selenium is IDE dependent and I must initiate the tests myself. I need something that automates them, independent of the IDE as described above.

Some advice is appreciated,

Thanks

Comment: Read about continuous integration. Test automation has nothing to do with that. CI, Continuous deployment and build pipeline are responsible for doing those works.

Comment: Right but I still need to test the new version

Comment: Why are people downvoting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for a Continuous Integration product - this will allow you to do what you're asking. Some popular names are:

- https://www.atlassian.com/software/bamboo
- https://jenkins-ci.org/

You can define a *build plan* there, which will watch your repo for changes and kick off a build when there are changes. Your tests can be executed as part of this build plan.

A typical build plan could look like this:

- Check out the sources
- Compile/package
- Run unit tests
- Deploy to a test server
- Run end-to-end tests

The result of the build will report any errors that occurred as part of the test plan execution.

Comment: I see, and what about the tests?